# How to check if text contains an @username? - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my create action in the comments controller I want to check if the comment text contains a "@ + username" so I can add it to my public activities.

```
if @comment.body.include?('  [HERE]  ')
```

maybe `User.all.username.any?` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You better use ruby regex to first find the user name from comment body matching pattern `@abc` and then user that username query database to find user

```
@comment.body.scan(/@(\w+)/).flatten.to_a.each do|username|
   if User.where(:username => username).any?
    # your code here 
   end
end
```

or search the users with single database query by passing the array

```
usernames = @comment.body.scan(/@(\w+)/).flatten.to_a

if User.where(:username => usernames).any?
    # your code here 
end
```

This will optimize the db query and will not load all users to memory.

Comment: The only suggestion I would add is to stuff the usernames from the regex into an array, then pass *that* to the database - that way, you only need to make a maximum of one DB query.

Comment: @Undo, that makes total sense to me sense.

Comment: returning NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass)

Comment: @MalekZalfana, updated now to use `scan` to return correct usernames instead of `match`

Comment: thanks man its working now, but the js resplonse isn't and its not returning any error, any thoughts

Comment: @MalekZalfana, which error you are seeing, can you paste the error/code please.

Comment: I'm getting an error, in the trace it says rendered create.js.erb and I only have alert and console.log to check if its working

Comment: Can you post controller and html/js code, that would be helpful to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A quick answer:

```
if User.pluck(:username).any? {|u| @comment.body.include?("@#{u}")}
  # ...
end
```

A better answer:

Why not use a javascript library to [auto-complete](https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete) the username? This is more user friendly, and scales better as the `User` table grows.